# Fuelphp migrations

Tags: php, mysql, orm, migration, fuelphp

Hi guys does any one know how to migrate an existing database to new schema ?
for example my current table schema is

id: int(10)
name: varchar(100)

and the table is already populated by production data. Later on I decided to add a new field to the table. The new table schema would be

id: int(10)
name: varchar(100)
age: int(3)

How I will migrate this without losing the data. Is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, but did you add the new field with `oil g migration add_age_to_table age:int`?

Comment: sorry for 2 days delayed reply.. I'll test that later when I got home.. :)